# Static library not included in resulting LLVM executable

Tags: c, llvm, static-linking

I am trying to compile a c program using LLVM and I am having trouble getting some static libraries included. I have successfully compiled those static libraries using LLVM and, for example, libogg.a is present, as is ogg.l.bc.

However, when I try to build the final program, it does not include the static ogg library. I've tried various compiler options with the most notable being:

```
gcc oggvorbis.c -O3 -Wall -I$OV_DIR/include -l$OV_DIR/lib/libogg.a -l$OV_DIR/lib/libvorbis.a -o test.exe
```

This results in the following output (directories shortened for brevity):

```
$OV_DIR/include/vorbis/vorbisfile.h:75: warning: ‘OV_CALLBACKS_DEFAULT’ defined but not used
$OV_DIR/include/vorbis/vorbisfile.h:82: warning: ‘OV_CALLBACKS_NOCLOSE’ defined but not used
$OV_DIR/include/vorbis/vorbisfile.h:89: warning: ‘OV_CALLBACKS_STREAMONLY’ defined but not used
$OV_DIR/include/vorbis/vorbisfile.h:96: warning: ‘OV_CALLBACKS_STREAMONLY_NOCLOSE’ defined but not used
llvm-ld: warning: Cannot find library '$OV_DIR/lib/ogg.l.bc'
llvm-ld: warning: Cannot find library '$OV_DIR/lib/vorbis.l.bc'
WARNING: While resolving call to function 'main' arguments were dropped!
```

I find this perplexing because $OV_DIR/lib/ogg.l.bc DOES exist, as does vorbis.l.bc and they are both readable (as are their containing directories) by everyone.

Does anyone have any idea with what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 3):

As unwind said,
-l is followed by the library name.

For example, in linux library naming conventions, 
if a library is named libogg,

-logg will find and choose the *best match in the library directories.

You can add a directory into the list:

> 1. -L option is one of the way to add the following folder to the list temporarily.
> 2. The environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH also affects the list on most of Linux/Unix > with GNU tools.

gcc may find both static and shared library files whose name matches with the requested library name.

For example,

> libogg.a
>   libogg.so

That's why there is a gcc option, -static

> -static
>   On systems that support dynamic linking, this prevents linking
>   with the shared libraries. On other
>   systems, this option has no effect.

If you just want to use a shared or static library file - directly, just as an object file,
then give their path without any option, like

```
gcc oggvorbis.c the_path/libogg.a
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I'll try using the static library file directly as an object file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `-l` [option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) expects paths. You should split those out, and use the `-L` option to set the paths, then just use plain library names with `-l`:

```
$ gcc oggvorbis.c -O3 -Wall -I$OV_DIR/include -L$OV_DIR/lib -logg -lvorbis -o test.exe
```

Also note that when used like this, you don't include the "lib" and ".a" parts of the library name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You can use paths with the -l option. This forces the compiler to use the specified file rather than expanding -logg. This is because the compiler prefers the dynamic shared library over the static library.

Either way, it doesn't explain the fact that it can't find the bytecode l.bc files even though they exist!